# calculate multidinmension array to get a new array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidinmension array like :

```
array(
   'phone' => array(
      'amount' => 100,
      'order'  => 10,
      'refund' => 10
    ),
   'amazon' => array(
      'amount' => 200,
      'order'  => 12,
      'refund' => 11
   )
)
```

I want to calculate this array to get a new array like this:

```
array(
   'amount' => 300,
   'order'  => 22,
   'refund' => 21
)
```

i want to reduce time and resource,but i have no idea except loop the array.I hope someone can achieve it more effective.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you're creating the original array you can make it that way upon creation, otherwise you'll need to loop through it.

Comment: emm,the original array is not created by me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$result = array();
foreach($arr as $key=>$val){
  foreach($val as $key1=>$val1){
    $result[$key1] += $val1;
  }
}
```

See demo [here](https://eval.in/100275)